# Should the public be able to vote on the actions of editing reviewers?

Tags: feature-request

Frankly I find the editor's powers draconian and wish there was a way for the public to easily express their opinion of rulings, such as "closed as primarily opinion-based".  It is a matter of opinion as to whether something is a matter of opinion, or duplicate or whatever, and the public should be able to readily override an editor's ruling via a vote.

I've personally experienced having my question shut down because the editor didn't understand a nuance of my question; I found that trying to appeal or change this was not going to be an easy practice so I gave up and had to seek help elsewhere.

I also see discussions that are theoretically asking for objective information but because various answers opine, the entire discussion is closed as being opinion based.  I suggest that it would be far better for the editor to flag individual answers as being unsubstantiated rather than closing the discussion.  Product-related questions, for instance, are especially plagued by this.  There are objective measures to be had for comparing products, and those objective differences are extremely valuable to know, so the forum should be left open for those willing to do the hard research.

Community appeal based voting could also have the side effect of getting users to think more about the appropriateness of various practices and engage them more at the editor level.

Comment: editing reviewers != editors != **Close Voters**, take some time to learn how the system actually works before suggesting that it needs to be changed... Close Votes are voted on through a review system, it usually takes 5 closevotes to close a question.

Comment: Yikes, sorry.  Forgive my poor nomenclature, I am not familiar with any but the basic usage side of SO.  That said, I did take the time to voice my frustrations, so my ask is that you filter those through the newby filter in case there might be something useful; if nothing else that some things might not be intuitive to newbies.

Comment: *the editor didn't understand a nuance of my question* dont be nuanced.  this isnt literature, dont make people linger over your question.  help them understand the nature of of by being clear and concise, so they can provide some help and get on with their lives.

Comment: @Plutonix.  I'd appreciate the benefit of the doubt here, the distinction didn't seem nuanced to me, or to several other members.  I'd dig it out, but it appears to have been deleted (cleanup process on old closed questions, maybe?)  I get it that you guys are doing a good service and have good intentions; I wouldn't be posting here if I wasn't trying to help, not tear down.

Comment: so, your use of the word *nuanced* was a polite reference to "the editor", rather than a characterization of the post.  Ok, I get it.  That *nuance* was lost on me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your use of the word "editor" with respect of the rest of your question suggest you might not quite be familiar with the workings of Stack Overflow, despite the fact that you are approaching 500 rep and have been a member for almost 5 years.

"Closed a primarily-opinion based" has absolutely nothing to do with editing.  Editing is solely related to editing the body (or title) of the question itself to correct issues with the post.  The act of closing questions for various reasons is related to the site's moderation and is performed both by the site's moderators **and** by regular community members such as yourself.

> I find the editor's powers draconian and wish there was a way for the public to easily express their opinion of rulings, such as "closed as primarily opinion-based". It is a matter of opinion as to whether something is a matter of opinion, or duplicate or whatever, and the public should be able to readily override an editor's ruling via a vote.

**Your wish is granted.**  The community can already override any close actions by any users.  If a question is incorrectly closed, users with 3K rep can vote to reopen the question.  And users with less than 3K rep can flag the post and have a diamond moderator review the question, however, moderators are not likely to override the community unless there is a serious error or misunderstanding.

> I've personally experienced having my question shut down because the editor didn't understand a nuance of my question; I found that trying to appeal or change this was not going to be an easy practice so I gave up and had to seek help elsewhere.

If you edited an explanation into your question after it was closed, it would have automatically been put into a review queue so other users can evaluate the edit and decide if the changes merited the question getting reopened.  If you left your explanation in the form of a comment, or if your edit did not do enough to convince other users that your question indeed needs to be reopened, then the question would likely have remained closed.

> I also see discussions that are theoretically asking for objective information but because various answers opine, the entire discussion is closed as being opinion based. I suggest that it would be far better for the editor to flag individual answers as being unsubstantiated rather than closing the discussion. Product-related questions, for instance, are especially plagued by this. There are objective measures to be had for comparing products, and those objective differences are extremely valuable to know, so the forum should be left open for those willing to do the hard research.

It is impossible to provide any kind of reasonable answer based on the info you have provided.  Improperly closed questions happen, but they can be fixed.  However, without a specific example (or examples), we can't provide you with any kind of objective feedback.  I will say that Stack Overflow is not a site for just any question.  There are very strict guidelines on what is on-topic and what is considered acceptable for the site.  If you are confused as to what to ask, I suggest you review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do a detailed response; I admit that in retrospect I didn't do the research I should have.  That said, take this as feedback that perhaps the process could be made more transparent to newbies. 

In the case of my question that was closed, I did post in the comments and several other users agreed, but I was unaware that there was a meta-discussion happening that I was not privy to.  Thanks again.

Comment: @N8allan Your situation is somewhat unique as you are such a long time member.  New users are provided at lot of information when asking their first questions.  You, however, pre-dated much of that feedback, so you woudn't have seen what other new users would have been given.  Likewise, any info you were given in 2009 would likely be outdated.  The site has changed a lot in the time since you first signed up.

Comment: @N8allan While the community general frowns upon users who refuse to heed any advice, they are generally receptive to users who want to try to learn from their mistakes.  If you have specific ideas on how to improve the user experience for new users without impacting the quality of the site, feel free to propose it in another Meta.StackOverflow question.  I would caution you to avoid words like draconian though.